# MySQL 8.0 service won't start "directory exists"

Tags: server, 20.04, mysql

Environment:

- Ubuntu 20.04 cloud image, initiated with cloud-config with total 9 hdds.
- mysql-server 8.0.27 installed with apt.
- Two logical volumes with four hdds each (sdb-e, sdf-i) mounted rw on `/mysql/data` and `/mysql/log`.
- User mysql owns `/mysql` and all subdirs and can write to them.
- Configuration file in `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf` defines `basedir` as `/var/lib/mysql` (where all the default stuff is from the installation) and `datadir` as `/mysql/data`.

Problem:

- Enable/start mysql.service fails the pre-check with a message that the directory `/mysql/data` already exists, and will not start.

How does one get around this catch22 situation?

Comment: Sounds like an `AppArmor` issue. Check your configuration to ensure the MySQL section has proper `[r,w]` values for the directories you’ve created 

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem:

```
# Allow directory changes in AppArmor
sudo sed -i '/\# Allow data files dir access/a /mysql/** rwk,' /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
sudo systemctl stop apparmor.service
sleep 10
sudo systemctl start apparmor.service
```

removed the lost+found folders from the `/mysql/` subfolders and initialized the db using

```
sudo -u mysql mysqld --initialize
```